# Dynamic nib loading with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I'm updating a nib without autolayout to one that has autolayout.

Today the nib basically contains two views:

1/ The view at the top is dynamically loaded from a nib using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil]
```

The nibs can have different height.

2/ The view at the bottom uses the remaining space.

So I'm not so sure how to do that cleanly. I'm willing to do anything codewise to get the cleanest and simplest way to handle this.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Show the code around loading the nib - where are you adding the subviews? what constraints are you currently adding? what does it do wrong?

Comment: shouldn't you use a container view for the outer one .. and indeed the inner one?

Comment: @Wain: My code is not really relevant as I was creating my second view programmatically, now I'd like to do as much as possible in IB using constraints. Contraints wise I want my first view to have a fixed height depending on my external nib, and my second one taking the remaining height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code you will need to add constraints to pin to the size of the view just loaded from the NIB to the initial frame size values. Then add it as a subview of whatever container view exists in your storyboard and pin the edges of the view to its new superview.

In the storyboard, pin the container view to the views around it.